Tanstack ReactQuery: No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one
So I'm looking around fora solve to this issue, theres no obvious reason and most of the threads I've found involve a mistake around dependencies which I dont seem to have
The error is the standard:
"No QueryClient set, use QueryClientProvider to set one"
index.tsx
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { QueryClient, QueryClientProvider } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { ReactQueryDevtools } from '@tanstack/react-query-devtools'
import IncidentBar from './app/IncidentBar';

const queryClient = new QueryClient();

ReactDOM.render(
  <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
    <IncidentBar/>
    <ReactQueryDevtools initialIsOpen={false} />
  </QueryClientProvider>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);

Incident Bar
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react'

import { useQuery } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import axios from 'axios';

const IncidentBar = () => {    
  const fetchStatus = async () => {
    const { data } = await axios.get('...data url...');
    return data;
  }

  const { data: incidentData } = useQuery('incidentStatus', fetchStatus)

  console.warn(incidentData)

  return (
    <div className="incident-container">
      <span className="mt-sm">
        <span className="mr-2">Notice:</span>
        <a href="https://a place you can look at statuses">
            error message goes here
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}

export default IncidentBar

versions in package.json
"@tanstack/react-query": "^4.36.1",
"@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.36.1",

Versions in lock
"node_modules/@tanstack/match-sorter-utils": {
  "version": "8.19.4",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@tanstack/match-sorter-utils/-/match-sorter-utils-8.19.4.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-Wo1iKt2b9OT7d+YGhvEPD3DXvPv2etTusIMhMUoG7fbhmxcXCtIjJDEygy91Y2JFlwGyjqiBPRozme7UD8hoqg==",
  "dependencies": {
    "remove-accents": "0.5.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=12"
  },
  "funding": {
    "type": "github",
    "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/tannerlinsley"
  }
},
"node_modules/@tanstack/query-core": {
  "version": "4.36.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@tanstack/query-core/-/query-core-4.36.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-DJSilV5+ytBP1FbFcEJovv4rnnm/CokuVvrBEtW/Va9DvuJ3HksbXUJEpI0aV1KtuL4ZoO9AVE6PyNLzF7tLeA==",
  "funding": {
    "type": "github",
    "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/tannerlinsley"
  }
},
"node_modules/@tanstack/react-query": {
  "version": "4.36.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@tanstack/react-query/-/react-query-4.36.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-y7ySVHFyyQblPl3J3eQBWpXZkliroki3ARnBKsdJchlgt7yJLRDUcf4B8soufgiYt3pEQIkBWBx1N9/ZPIeUWw==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/query-core": "4.36.1",
    "use-sync-external-store": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "funding": {
    "type": "github",
    "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/tannerlinsley"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-native": "*"
  },
  "peerDependenciesMeta": {
    "react-dom": {
      "optional": true
    },
    "react-native": {
      "optional": true
    }
  }
},
"node_modules/@tanstack/react-query-devtools": {
  "version": "4.36.1",
  "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/@tanstack/react-query-devtools/-/react-query-devtools-4.36.1.tgz",
  "integrity": "sha512-WYku83CKP3OevnYSG8Y/QO9g0rT75v1om5IvcWUwiUZJ4LanYGLVCZ8TdFG5jfsq4Ej/lu2wwDAULEUnRIMBSw==",
  "dependencies": {
    "@tanstack/match-sorter-utils": "^8.7.0",
    "superjson": "^1.10.0",
    "use-sync-external-store": "^1.2.0"
  },
  "funding": {
    "type": "github",
    "url": "https://github.com/sponsors/tannerlinsley"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.36.1",
    "react": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.0 || ^17.0.0 || ^18.0.0"
  }
},

Have tried moving QueryClientProvider and the Incident bar App component and moving the IncidentBar anywhere else in the app
Update: so it seems that it'll work if the component isnt in a seperate file which leads me to the webpack config (inherited)
heres what I've done in the config so far
const path = require("path");
const { SourceMapDevToolPlugin, ProvidePlugin } = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");
const FileManagerPlugin = require("filemanager-webpack-plugin");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const CssMinimizerPlugin = require("css-minimizer-webpack-plugin");
const MomentLocalesPlugin = require("moment-locales-webpack-plugin");
const MomentTimezoneDataPlugin = require("moment-timezone-data-webpack-plugin");
const { InjectManifest } = require("workbox-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = (env) =>
{
    const isProduction = env !== undefined && 'production' in env && typeof env.production === 'boolean' ? env.production : false;

    const config = {
        mode: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
        bail: isProduction,
        resolve: {
            extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
            fallback: {
                'process/browser': require.resolve('process/browser'),
            }
        },
        entry: './src/index.tsx',
        devtool: isProduction ? undefined : 'eval-source-map',
        devServer: {
            https: true,
            //https: false,

            client: {
                logging: "none",
            },
            static: {
                directory: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
                publicPath: '/'
            },
            historyApiFallback: true,
            hot: true,
            open: true,


            //port: 'auto'
            port: 3001
        },
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'build'),
            publicPath: '/',
            filename: isProduction ? 'js/[name].[contenthash].js' : '[name].js',
            assetModuleFilename: 'assets/[contenthash][ext]',
        },
        optimization: {
            minimize: isProduction,
            nodeEnv: isProduction ? 'production' : 'development',
            minimizer: [
                '...',
                new CssMinimizerPlugin(),
            ],
            // runtimeChunk: 'single',
            runtimeChunk: false,
            splitChunks: false,
            // {
            //  chunks: 'all',
            //  cacheGroups: {
            //      styles: {
            //          name: 'main',
            //          test: /\.(css|scss)$/,
            //          chunks: 'all',
            //          enforce: true,
            //      },
            //      vendor: {
            //          test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            //          name: 'vendors',
            //          chunks: 'all'
            //      }
            //  }
            // },
            moduleIds: 'deterministic'
        },
        module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
                    exclude: /(node_modules|__test__)/,
                    use: {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                        options: {
                            presets: [
                                ['@babel/preset-env'],
                                '@babel/react'
                            ],
                            plugins: [
                                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators', {
                                    legacy: true
                                }],
                                '@babel/syntax-dynamic-import',
                                ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', {
                                    regenerator: true,
                                }],
                                'react-hot-loader/babel',
                                ['@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties', {
                                    loose: false
                                }],
                                ['lodash'],
                            ],
                            compact: true
                        }
                    },
                },
                {
                    test: /\.tsx?$/,
                    use: 'ts-loader',
                    exclude: /(node_modules|__test__)/,
                },
                {
                    test: /\.d\.ts$/,
                    use: 'ignore-loader'
                },
                {
                    test: /\.css$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            options: { publicPath: '../' },
                        },
                        'css-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(scss|sass)$/,
                    use: [
                        {
                            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                            options: { publicPath: '../' },
                        },
                        'css-loader',
                        'sass-loader'
                    ]
                },
                {
                    test: /\.(svg|png|jpe?g|gif|webp|ttf|eot|otf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$/i,
                    type: 'asset',
                }
            ]
        },
        plugins: [
            isProduction && new SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
                test: /\.(js)$/,
                filename: '../sourcemaps/[file].map',
                append: '\n//# sourceMappingURL=[file].map',
                fileContext: 'js'
            }),

            new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
                filename: "css/[name].[contenthash].css",
                ignoreOrder: true
            }),

            new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                filename: 'index.html',
                template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public', 'index.html'),
                minify: isProduction ? {
                    removeComments: true,
                    collapseWhitespace: true,
                    removeRedundantAttributes: true,
                    useShortDoctype: true,
                    removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                    removeStyleLinkTypeAttributes: true,
                    keepClosingSlash: true,
                    minifyJS: true,
                    minifyCSS: true,
                    minifyURLs: true,
                } : false,
            }),

            new CopyWebpackPlugin(isProduction ? {
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: '**/*',
                        context: './public',
                        globOptions: {
                            ignore: [ '**/*.html' ],
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        from: './src/locales',
                        to: './locales',
                        toType: 'dir'
                    },
                ],
            } : {
                patterns: [
                    {
                        from: './appConfig.json',
                        to: './appConfig.json',
                        toType: 'file'
                    },
                    {
                        from: './src/locales',
                        to: './locales',
                        toType: 'dir'
                    },
                ]
            }),

            isProduction && new FileManagerPlugin({
                events: {
                    onStart: {
                        delete: [
                            { source: './sourcemaps', options: { force: true }},
                            { source: './build/js/*', options: {}},
                        ]
                    },
                    onEnd: {
                        copy: [
                            { source: './build/js/*.js', destination: './sourcemaps/' },
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }),

            new ProvidePlugin({
                $: 'jquery',
                jQuery: 'jquery',
                'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
                _: 'underscore',
                moment: 'moment',
                Moment: 'moment',
                process: 'process/browser',
                Buffer: ['buffer', 'Buffer'],
            }),

            isProduction && new InjectManifest({
                swSrc: './src/init/src-sw.js',
                swDest: 'sw.js',
                maximumFileSizeToCacheInBytes: 12 * 1024 * 1024 // 12MB
            }),

            new MomentLocalesPlugin({
                localesToKeep: ['en-nz', 'en-au']
            }),

            new MomentTimezoneDataPlugin({
                startYear: 2018,
                endYear: new Date().getFullYear() + 1,
                matchCountries: ['NZ', 'AU']
            }),
        ]
    };

    if(Array.isArray(config.plugins))
    {
        config.plugins = config.plugins.filter(plugin => plugin !== undefined && plugin !== false);
    }

    return config;
};


I made a sample with your description and it works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-yances?file=src%2Fmain.jsx,src%2FApp.jsx,index.html&terminal=dev

Yes it should, it's exactly the docs. I think the issue could be with webpack chunking
